# Replace all characters between parenthesis

Tags: bash

I've just came from Windows 8 and having a huge issue right now. I am now on Ubuntu 12.10 I used FileHistory to back up my data to an external hard drive, and now all of my files have been backed up in addition to appending a timestamp in the file name.

I am in need of removing everything between parenthesis that starts off with "(2012_" and ends with ")".

Can anyone help me with this? Here's a screenshot of a list of files I'm trying to fix:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2526790/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-30%2021%3A19%3A06.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
rename 's/\s\([^\)]+\)//' *.*
```

We can thank Larry Wall for that one.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Current files:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 guru None 0 Dec  1 09:14 a (2002).iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 guru None 0 Dec  1 09:14 b_(2003_2).iso
```

Renaming the files:

```
$ (
> IFS=""
> for i in *
> do
>  mv "$i" $(echo $i | sed 's/\(.*\)(.*)\(.*\)/\1\2/')
> done
> )
```

After running the above command:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 guru None 0 Dec  1 09:14 a .iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 guru None 0 Dec  1 09:14 b_.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```bsh
for FILE in *; do
    mv "$FILE" "${FILE%(*}${FILE##*)}"
done
```

This works because `${FILE%(*}` removes the smallest match of `(*` from the right, i.e. everything including and after the last open parenthesis, while `${FILE##*)}` removes the largest match of `*)` from the left, i.e. everything including and before the last closing parenthesis. Combining them, you should get everything except that last parenthesis. This should work even if any of the filenames have other parentheses in them as well.

Note, this kind of script-moving is tricky and can potentially screw your filenames up. I recommend using `echo` instead of `mv` in the above to confirm that it really does the right thing for every single file, first.

And the double quotes are important too since you have spaces in your filenames.

If you want to remove the final space before the open parenthesis too, just include it in the first pattern: `${FILE% (*}`.